# Number of digits after decimal using String.format

Tags: java, string, format

I know to convert a double value to string , I can do like this :

```
String value = String.format("%f", 10.0000);
```

Also I can control the number of digits after decimal using this :

```
String value = String.format("%.3f", 10.000000);
```

But my problem is that, I am receiving number of digits after decimal point through a variable.
How can I use String.format to print the number of digits after decimal provided by the user.

Regards,
Anuj

Comment: an example would be helpful, expected input/output

Answer (score 5):

```
String value = String.format("%."+x+"f", 10.000000);
```

where x is number of digits.